# Video not playing in lightbox, goes straight to youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the title says, I'm using prettyPhoto and when the thumbnail is clicked it just takes the browser straight to youtube instead of playing the video inside of lightbox. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>My Name | Designer</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
            <meta name="viewport" comtemt="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
            <script src="PP/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="PP/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
            <script src="PP/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <header>
              <a href="index.html" id="logo">
                <h1>My Name</h1>
                <h2>Designer</h2>
              </a>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
                   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div id="wrapper">
              <section>
                <ul id="gallery">
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hu6CIISutes" rel="prettyPhoto">
                      <img src="img/numbers-01.jpg" alt="">
                      <p>Logo Animation</p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </section>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
          });
        </script>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It works fine here: http://jsbin.com/sopozumave/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I have no idea whats up. You think it could have something to do with conflicting CSS files?

Comment: My guess is that prettyPhoto script isn't being loaded, probably due to an error in the `src` path. Use the browser dev tools to verify that your js (both jquery and prettyPhoto) is actually being loaded.

Comment: Check for error in console if there is any. code seems to be ok, there must be some other issue